# Bad operand type for unary str in python networking

Tags: python, sockets, cmd, telnet

I was learning to bind and listen to sockets, so when I done writing the code connect to given localhost through cmd, it is getting the following error.

```
s.listen(5)

conn, addr = s.accept()

print('connected with: ', + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/vineel/Desktop/Python34/PYTHON NETWORKING/bindsockets.py", line 19, in <module>

   print('connected with: ', + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))

TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print('connected with: ', + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
```

should be (no comma):

```
print('connected with: ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
```